# SQL Server separate: FirstName, MiddleName and LastName

Tags: mysql, sql, split

Good day!
I get a "Varchar" which is the full name of a client, and need to split this "varchar" as:

- "FirstName MidleName MiddleNameTwo LastName "
- Need to enter the "FirstName" on "Col1"
- Need to enter the "MiddleName, MiddleNameTwo in" col2 "
- Need to enter the "LastName" in "Col3"

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide samples of what the names look like.  Also, are you using SQL Server (as suggested by the title) or MySQL (as suggested by the tags)?

Comment: Is this a fixed set of names where you know there won't be any oddities like "Mary Jane Vaughan Williams", where "Mary Jane" is the first name, and "Vaughan Williams" is the last name? Bear in mind that names are insanely complicated and many of them don't follow any general rules that you could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use subqueries for this task

```
 INSERT INTO names(firstname, middlename, lastname)
 SELECT substringfunctionofyours(name), substringfunctionofyours(name), 
 substringfunctionofyours(name) FROM namefield
```

**keep in mind this is just a dummy query it won't work if you use it like this**

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the input method to 4 separate fields ?

If you can't, then implement a specific delimeter between the different parts of the string ?
In cases where the last name is built with 2 words, there is no deterministic way of processing the string if the delimeter is [space] or any other character like '-' or ' which are common in names.

Using a delimeter like '|' :

```
Declare @FullName varchar(100) = 'FirstName|MidleName|MiddleNameTwo|LastName'
Print 'FirstName = ' + Substring(@FullName,1,charindex('|',@FullName)-1)
SELECT @FullName = Substring(@FullName,charindex('|',@FullName)+1,len(@fullName))
Print 'MiddleName1 = ' + Substring(@FullName,1,charindex('|',@FullName)-1)
SELECT @FullName = Substring(@FullName,charindex('|',@FullName)+1,len(@fullName))
Print 'MiddleName2 = ' + Substring(@FullName,1,charindex('|',@FullName)-1)
SELECT @FullName = Substring(@FullName,charindex('|',@FullName)+1,len(@fullName))
Print 'LastName = ' + @FullName
```

This will also work if you don't have one of the parts, as long as you maintain the structure.

```
Declare @FullName varchar(100) = 'FirstName|MidleName||LastName'
Print 'FirstName = ' + Substring(@FullName,1,charindex('|',@FullName)-1)
SELECT @FullName = Substring(@FullName,charindex('|',@FullName)+1,len(@fullName))
Print 'MiddleName1 = ' + Substring(@FullName,1,charindex('|',@FullName)-1)
SELECT @FullName = Substring(@FullName,charindex('|',@FullName)+1,len(@fullName))
Print 'MiddleName2 = ' + Substring(@FullName,1,charindex('|',@FullName)-1)
SELECT @FullName = Substring(@FullName,charindex('|',@FullName)+1,len(@fullName))
Print 'LastName = ' + @FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a name like this  `"ABC DEF GHI"`

now you want `First Name`, `Middle Name` and `last Name`  From this string.

Here We Go

```
 Select 
 Substring(Cast('ABC DEF GHI' as nvarchar),0,charindex(' ',Cast('ABC DEF GHI' as nvarchar))) as Col1,
 Substring(Cast('ABC DEF GHI' as nvarchar),charindex(' ',Cast('ABC DEF GHI' as nvarchar)),4)as Col2,
 Substring(Cast('ABC DEF GHI' as nvarchar),8,charindex(' ',Cast('ABC DEF GHI' as nvarchar)))as Col3
```

**Note:** `This is MSSQL SERVER Query and Substring Function is Built in in MSSQL SERVER`